# Where does the ledger or the stateDB get stored in a peer filesystem in Fabric

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am studying and running samples from the **Hyperledger Fabric** samples .

According to my understanding :

There are two place which "store" data in Hyperledger Fabric:-

->the **ledger**

->the **state database**

The state database is simply an indexed view into the chain’s/ledger's transaction log, it can therefore be regenerated from the chain at any time.

There are currently two options for the state database: an embedded **LevelDB** or an external **CouchDB**.

I want to know where the blockchain/ledger or the database gets stored in the filesystem . Is it stored in a specific directory or a specific port (in case of levelDB as well as couchdb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the levelDB one, it is stored under the path /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData, in which you can find two directories called **chains** and **stateLeveldb**. You can try to go into the peer container and have a look.

Comment: thanks . how to navigate to that docker container . 
Because as far as i saw . i couldnt find any .
I am running the IBM blockhain insurance application from
https://github.com/IBM/build-blockchain-insurance-app

these are my docker images : https://imgur.com/a/aweXpZL

Comment: @Skadoosh I assume you have some peer containers running. You can run "docker ps -a" to look for the list of containers. Let's say you have one named peer1.org1.example.com, you can run "docker exec -it peer1.org1.example.com bash" to go into the container.

Comment: Thanks again . You can see the picture link i shared . those are the docker images . i navigated to shop-peer using the command u mentioned . there are no folders in it . however when i use the command docker run -it shop-peer bash . there is a var/hyperledger/production folder but no db directories found . 
Please help

Comment: Found it . THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way

1. use command `docker ps` to view all your peers then choose a peer to view data inside
2. `docker exec -it container_id bash` to open peer cli
3. change directory to /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData then you can see folder named **chains**, your data u need is place inside